# Copy function with Range(Cells(a,b), Cells(c,d)) not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below which supposedly copies the values in a range of cells and pastes them at another location, but it is not working for some reason.

```
 For sheetnumber = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Set currentsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetnumber)
    currentsheet.Range(Cells(11, 4), Cells(25, 4)).Copy
    currentsheet.Paste Destination:=currentsheet.Cells(11, 3)
 Next sheetnumber
```

However, when i use `currentsheet.Range("D11:D25").Copy`, it works and is able to copy the selected range of cells. So may I know why cant `currentsheet.Range(Cells(11, 4), Cells(25, 4)).Copy` work? Or is there another alternative such that I can write `currentsheet.Range("D11:D25").Copy` such that my column (D in this case) can be expressed in terms of a variable? Thank you.

Comment: `Cells(11, 4)` is equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Cells(11,4)`, and in your case currentsheet is not always active

Comment: ahh i see, thanks!@KirillTkachenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a sheet qualifier (object) for your `Cells`, like below:

```vb
For sheetnumber = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Set currentsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetnumber)
    currentsheet.Range(currentsheet.Cells(11, 4), currentsheet.Cells(25, 4)).Copy
    currentsheet.Paste Destination:=currentsheet.Cells(11, 3)
 Next sheetnumber
```

Comment: a `With currentsheet … End With` block would fit in this case

Comment: great, thanks alot! @Dean

Answer (score 1):

Dean gave you the solution

here's some other hints to enhance your code

- you could avoid to Copy and Paste in two statements by using the `Destination` parameter of the `Copy()` method of `Range` class
- use `With … End With` blocks to ensure proper range qualifications and avoid repeating the same variable name

here's the code

```
Dim sheetnumber As Long
With ThisWorkbook ' reference 'ThisWorkbook' workbook
    For sheetnumber = 2 To .Sheets.Count ' loop from 2 to referenced workbook sheets number
        With .Sheets(sheetnumber) ' reference referenced workbook 'sheetnumber'th sheet
            .Range(.Cells(11, 4), .Cells(25, 4)).Copy Destination:=.Cells(11, 3) ' copy and paste in one shot . see all ranges are linke to the referenced sheet via the preceeding dot
        End With
    Next
End With
```